# Trying to send birthday greetings to someone on 18th birthday through Kentico

Tags: kentico, contactgroups

I am trying to figure a way to send birthday greetings on someone's 18th birthday through Kentico 11. I am trying to use contact groups, but I don't see a way to identify birthdays through the contact groups.

Is there a way to pull/identify someones birthday from the contact information. Is this custom programming?

Right now I have an excel spreadsheet with birth date and age, but I can't map to birth date and age currently.

Or can I only do this as a scheduled task?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without customizing the Contact record, you'd use a scheduled task.  If you have a custom property for the birth date on the contact's record, then you should be able to use Marketing Automation to check that value.  Keep in mind, MA uses some sort of trigger to process those records.

It may be better to simply use a scheduled task with a custom email template you can personalize with the contacts information.  Run the scheduled task once per day and see if the contact's birthday is equal to the day and month, then send them that email.